# Add a form after ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

How i can add form after ul? Here is my code:

```
<article>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione repudiandae possimus dolore perferendis vel magni odio in architecto corrupti consequuntur.

    <a class="open" href="#">Add comment</a>
</article>
<ul class="children">
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum.</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
</ul>

<hr>

<article>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione repudiandae possimus dolore perferendis vel magni odio in architecto corrupti consequuntur.

    <a class="open" href="#">Add comment</a>
</article>
<ul class="children">
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum.</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
</ul>
```

and jquery:

```
$('.open').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $(this).parent().after('<form><input type="text"></form>');
});
```

question is: how i can add form after ul list, currently is inserted after article.

Here is demo: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9q1aao0e/5/)

**EDIT:**

How add form after article if ul after article not exist?

**ANSWER:**

```
$('.quick_reply').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if ($(this).parent().next('ul').length > 0) {
        $(this).parent().next('ul').after('<form><input type="text"></form>');
    } else {
        $(this).parent().after('<form><input type="text"></form>');
    }

});
```

Comment: @ArunPJohny I think he want a dynamic form, not necessary an existing one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `next('ul')` to find the `ul` related to the `a`:

```
$(this).parent().next('ul').after('Form after ul');
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9q1aao0e/2/)

I'm obviously assuming here that `Form after ul` is just a placeholder you're using to make your question clearer, and that your actual code does include the `form`,

Comment: updated,  
How add form after article if ul after article not exist?

Comment: That makes no sense. How can you click on the link in the article if the article doesnt exist?

Comment: sorry, this works like comments on stackoverflow, post is a article, after post i have list with comments (ul), when list is empty isn't displayed ul list.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('<form>').insertAfter($(this).closest('article').next('ul'));
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/9q1aao0e/3/

Comment: How add form after article if ul after article not exist?

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/

The .insertAfter() jQuery method should work as given in the jQuery docs above with examples.

Comment: How add form after article if ul after article not exist?

Comment: Add a id to the article and then use the insertAfter() method.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.open').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if ($(this).parent().next('ul').length > 0) {
        $(this).parent().next('ul').after('<form><input type="text"></form>');
    } else {
        $(this).parent().after('<form><input type="text"></form>');
    }

});
```